# Unable to load Termux pip

Tags: python, telegram-bot, termux, telebot

I can't Download Termux pip

1- E: Unable to locate package telebot
This is when I want to download pkg

2- No command pip found, did you mean:

Command pic in package groff                  Command ip in package iproute2

Command php in package php                    Command php in package php7

Command pil in package picolisp               Command pup in package pup

Command ip in package termux-tools            Command zip in package zip

This is when I want to download pip

---

I want Solution to the problem

Comment: So you'll need to install pip first. Or find where it is located to be able to run it. What system are you on?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While you do not provide much in the way of specifics, I can only think of a few things that *may* be the problem:

- If you have the Play Store version of Termux, it might be difficult to get `pkg` and `apt` to work properly, so uninstall it (assuming you don't have any non-replaceable files in the Termux cache/storage) and install the one from the GitHub repo at the [Termux app releases page](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/releases). Check your phone's processor architecture with Google if unsure. The Play Store version is out-of-date.
- Run `apt update && apt upgrade` before trying to install other packages. This will ensure that the basic, already-present Termux packages are up-to-date and functional.
- Finally, run `apt-get install python` to get pip functionality, rather than trying to install pip directly. Afterwards, any commands involving pip should work.

Answer (score 0):

The `pip` package on Termux is provided by the `python-pip` package.

`pkg install python-pip` should install it for you (assuming your system is configured correctly.)